# Particles follow cursor on mousemove (Javascript - Canvas)

Tags: javascript, canvas, mousemove

I'm trying to create a simple animation where some particles animation follow the cursor, but i'm having trouble with it.

I've created a fiddle to replicate the issue : [Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmcxjaof/1/)

Right now my particles appear, but when you move the cursor over the section, they suddenly disappear. I know my error comes from my `mousemove()` function, but i can't figure out what is wrong with it..

here is my mousemove function :

```
function mouseMove(e) {
        var posx = posy = 0;
        if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
            posx = e.pageX;
            posy = e.pageY;
        }
        else if (e.clientX || e.clientY)    {
            posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
            posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        }
        target.x = posx;
        target.y = posy;
    }
```

Comment: it seams that you are not taking in account the `<div class="section particles" id="services">` dom element and the top page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mouse coordinate X, Y is relative to the top/left corner of the web page, probably mousemove event is attached to document, not to the canvas. Attach the mosemove event to the canvas

```
document.getElementById('services-canvas').addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);
```

And use the elemnt ofset:

```
target.x = e.offsetX;
target.y = e.offsetY;
```

If you would like the mouse to be in the centre of figure, then use  e.offsetY-something where something is half of height of figure

Comment: I've modified the following : `if(!('ontouchstart' in document.getElementById('services')))` but it's still badly positionned.. I've also tried modifying `posx = e.pageX;` and `posy = e.pageY;` to `posx = e.pageX / 2` and `posy = e.pageY / 2` but the particles aren't in the right position

Comment: @Perdixo 
In mousemove use:     target.x = e.offsetX;    target.y = e.offsetY; and attach the event to the canvas: document.getElementById('services-canvas').addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove);

Answer (score 0):

So your particles do actually follow the mouse from what I have seen in . However, it seems that they are way lower in the y position that you would expect.You need to do this to make it work properly:

```
target.y = posy -300;
```

I have tried it and it worked with this little change. Hope this helped :D