# How I apply the Particle Mousemove to the Body of the Html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Our Homepage

[image: Our Homepage]

This is the Mousemove particle shows

[image: This is the Mousemove particle shows]

As you can see in the image, it only applies on the side of the web. it wouldn't
applies to the whole web.

Can you give us some advice seniors on how we completely work according to its order.
Thx for the help :) <3

if you have some questions about the code. I'll comment it to the comment box

Comment: MaxiGui thx for the Edit :)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? That is quite not clear...

Comment: What do you mean by `Particle Mouse move`?

Comment: @MaxiGui, I just want only to achieve the mousemove function particle will apply to my whole web page. it doesn't work on its order. it just only work on the side of web page which it shows on the second image. thx for the reply :)

Comment: @iamcastelli Shows some objects when the mouse cursor is moving. thx for the reply :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Particles follow cursor on mousemove (Javascript - Canvas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60152196/particles-follow-cursor-on-mousemove-javascript-canvas)

Comment: Oh, you mean the colors circles at the far left of the bottom screenshot. It appears you applied the effects to the body/html container, and the content of the page(cards) are placed on top of it so you cannot see them. I think the best way is to have an absolutely positioned element whose position is updated on mouse move and follows the cursor, then add the particles to that element.

Comment: Im sorry for the late replies, Im just new to this forums, also Im new of interaction of other people thx. :) Seniors, if you want to check my code, maybe i'll put it here on the comment box thx. :)

Comment: @iamcastelli can you give me some samples? Im just literally a freshmen student. Im sorry hehehe thx <3

Comment: You could try reading through this sandbox [here](https://codepen.io/renatorib/pen/gBLDA) or use something like [sketch.js](https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/foktm)

Comment: @iamcastelli Thx for the suggestion, It work enough to the absolute position but didn't work on the whole page and also it add some problems it won't click to it's object.

Comment: @iamcastelli Senior could you check my code. :'( to achieve the web that I want. thx                               Here is the Link https://codepen.io/jeckoders26/pen/XWdwQqr

Comment: I am very grateful for those who want to answer and reply thx :) <3